# Запретить элементу переводить на себя фокус

Tags: html, css, javascript

Приветствую. Есть вопрос. Как запретить диву при клике на нем переводить на себя фокус?
Благодарю.

Comment: а можно узнать - зачем вам такая способность? 
Ну то-есть что плохого в том, что div получит фокус?

Comment: Есть у меня написанный контрол изменения размера текста, сделан на HTML и CSS (не стандартный <select>. а свой) и вот выделив например в каком-то месте в диве текст, я хочу сменить размер шрифта, кликаю на свой контрол, он переводит на себя фокус и соответственно слетает выделение с выделенного мною текста. Мне нужно чтобы не слетало))) Грубо объяснил, но на скорую.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте это http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/ и почитайте тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215211/dont-lose-focus-when-clicking-another-element

В примере triggerhandler-а видно, что, выделив часть текста в input-е и нажав на кнопку ".trigger( "focus" )", выделение не снимается.

Comment: Спасибо. Это решение интересно, но мне не подходит, во всяком случае все равно еще раз спасибо.

Comment: Смотрите - когда вы выделили текст на странице - его можно получить следующим образом:
<pre>
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}

и тогда при обработке нажатия на ваш контрол делаем так:

$('#ID').click(function(e){
  selected_txt = getSelectionText()
  .....
}